# Mockito Class Copies Parameters

Tags: java, mockito

I am starting with Mockito and am currently trying to get coverage over a class and method where the class uses the constructor arguments to initialize its attributes. Its general shape is:

```
    public class MyExampleClass {
        private ClassType1 attributeType1;
        private ClassType2 attributeType2;

        public int returnsEnumInt()

        public MyExampleClass(ClassType3 argument1, ClassType2 argument2) {
            attributeType2 = argument2;
            if(argument1 != null) {
                attributeType1 = (ClassType1)argument1.getSomeValue();
            }
        }
    }

    public int returnsEnumInt() {
        if(attributeType1 != null) {
            int return_value = attributeType1.returnAnInt();
            if (return_value == 1)
                return 1;
            else if (return_value == 2)
                return 2;
            else
                return 3;
        } else {
            return 3;
        }
    }
```

My first hurdle would be to get inside the constructor's if case. With the bellow, the coverage shows the argument type3Object passed is null. Can I make type3Object non-null, without having to go through the implementation of its constructor?

```
    @Mock ClassType3 type3Object;
    @Mock ClassType2 type2Object;
    @InjectMocks private MyExampleClass exampleClassObject = new MyExampleClass(type3Object, type2Object);

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }
```

The second issue is how to mock methods called by the class' attributes, since they only copy the mock objects I give to the constructor? In this case, it would be `int return_value = attributeType1.returnAnInt();` , where I want to mock returnAnInt() and control the return value with something similar to 
 `Mockito.when( /*attributeType1 or type3Object?*/.requestAudioFocus(any(ClassType1.class))).thenReturn(1);`

The examples I have seen typically involve a mock object calling a class method directly, and changing the return value of said method, but nothing a bit more twisty as what I need, and as someone new to Mockito, I probably don't know how to define this search better.

Any input is greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you add this on top of your class @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) and let me know if it is still null or not.

Comment: I had it on top of the class running the tests; are you reffering to that spot or to add it on top of the actual class being tested?